# ArrayAdapter only shows last added thumbnail picture in list view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my app, I have a listView which shows employees, every item has it's own name, email and a thumbnail. everything works fine but the thumbnails. My ArrayAdapter, instead of showing all the employees profile pictures as thumbnail, works like this:

- does show all default pictures, which is automatically selected when user does not choose any picture for the specific employee. (default picture is in drawable folder: `"android.resource://com.witchking.modiryar/" + R.drawable.default_pic;`
- does show last inserted employee's picture as thumbnail
- if I go back to previous activity and I return to the list, list won't show even the last picture.
- if I have 2 or more employees with same picture, and I create another employee again with the same picture, list will show all the employees with picture same as the last inserted employee's picture!

here is a picture for you to better understand what I am facing:

my problem with adapter:

[image]

1. employee harry potter added with default picture
2. employee Frodo bagins added with picture named "A"
3. employee list after going back to main activity and returning to this activity
4. employee iron man added with picture named "B"
5. employee super man added with picture named "A" again

and here are my codes:

ArrayAdapter getView() method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View myView = convertView;
    String path ="android.resource://com.witchking.modiryar/" + R.drawable.default_pic;
    Uri uri = null;

    if (myView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listviewitem, null);
    }

    PersonHandler myPerson = getItem(position);
    if (myPerson != null){
        TextView firstLine = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        TextView secondLine = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
        ImageView profilePicture = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        if (myPerson.getPersonProfilePictureUrl() != null){
            uri = Uri.parse(myPerson.getPersonProfilePictureUrl());
        }else {
            uri = Uri.parse(myPerson.getPersonProfilePictureUrl());
        }

        firstLine.setText(myPerson.getPersonFullName());
        profilePicture.setImageURI(uri);

        switch (personType)
        {
            case 'S': //person type student
                secondLine.setText(myPerson.getPersonStudentNumber());
                break;
            case 'E': //person type employee
                secondLine.setText(myPerson.getPersonEmail());
                break;
            case 'M': //person type Masters
                secondLine.setText(myPerson.getPersonEmail());
                break;
        }
    }
    return myView;
}
```

`PersonHandler` is a class to handle queries based on type of person on different activities. here is the getPersonList() method:

```
    public List<PersonHandler> getPersonList(SQLiteDatabase sqldb, char personType){
    Cursor cursor;
    String fullName = null;
    String stdNumber = null;
    String email = null;
    String query = null;
    String path = "android.resource://com.witchking.modiryar/" + R.drawable.exclamation;
    String[] columnName = new String[3];

    List<PersonHandler> listPerson=new ArrayList<PersonHandler>();

    /*
    * dar in ghesmat query motenaseb ba personType
    * ejra migardad
    * query selected by person type
    */

    switch (personType) {
        case 'S':
            query = "select * from " + "tbl_Students";

            break;
        case 'E':
            query = "select * from " + "tbl_Employees";
            break;
        case 'M':
            query = "select * from " + "tbl_Master";
            break;
    }

    cursor = sqldb.rawQuery(query, null);



    /*
    * dar in ghesmat barname check mikonad ke agar cursor khali bood
    * yani hich daneshjoo, karmand, ya ostadi add nashode
    * pas bar asase personType tasmim migirad ke peyghame monaseb ra namayesh dahad
    * checking if cursor is null and displaying proper message
    * the message is added as an item in list
    */

    int cnt = cursor.getCount();

    if (cursor.getCount() <= 0){
        PersonHandler newPerson=new PersonHandler();
        newPerson.setPersonProfilePictureUrl(path);

        switch (personType) {
            case 'S':
                fullName = "هیچ دانشجویی اضافه نشده";
                stdNumber = "از منو گزینه دانشجوی جدید را انتخاب نمایید";
                newPerson.setPersonFullName(fullName);
                newPerson.setPersonStudentNumber(stdNumber);
                break;
            case 'E':
                fullName = "هیچ کارمندی اضافه نشده";
                email = "از منو گزینه کارمند جدید را انتخاب نمایید";
                newPerson.setPersonFullName(fullName);
                newPerson.setPersonEmail(email);
                break;
            case 'M':
                fullName = "هیچ استادی اضافه نشده";
                email = "از منو گزینه استاد جدید را انتخاب نمایید";
                newPerson.setPersonFullName(fullName);
                newPerson.setPersonEmail(email);
                break;
        }

        listPerson.add(newPerson);

        /*
        * dar in ghesmat bar asase personType barname tasmim migirad
        * ke field haye monasb ra bar asase query voroodi az cursor
        * farakhani konad
        * if cursor is not null, app selects proper columns based on person type
        */
    }else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            PersonHandler newPerson=new PersonHandler();

            switch (personType) {
                case 'S':
                    newPerson.setPersonFirstName(cursor.getString(1));  //First Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonLastName(cursor.getString(2));   //Last Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonEmail(cursor.getString(5));      //Email or StudentNumber Column
                    newPerson.setPersonProfilePictureUrl(cursor.getString(7));  //Picture Url Column
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    newPerson.setPersonFirstName(cursor.getString(1));  //First Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonLastName(cursor.getString(2));   //Last Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonEmail(cursor.getString(3));      //Email or StudentNumber Column
                    newPerson.setPersonProfilePictureUrl(cursor.getString(7));  //Picture Url Column
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    newPerson.setPersonFirstName(cursor.getString(1));  //First Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonLastName(cursor.getString(2));   //Last Name Column
                    newPerson.setPersonEmail(cursor.getString(3));      //Email or StudentNumber Column
                    newPerson.setPersonProfilePictureUrl(cursor.getString(7));  //Picture Url Column
                    break;
            }

            newPerson.setPersonFullName(newPerson.getPersonFirstName() + " " + newPerson.getPersonLastName());
            listPerson.add(cursor.getPosition(), newPerson);

            cursor.moveToNext();
            newPerson = null;
        }
    }
    return listPerson;
}
```

and finally my onCreate() method in the activity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_employees);
    context = this;
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = openOrCreateDatabase("ModirYar.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    char personType = 'E';

    PersonHandler EmployeePerson = new PersonHandler();
    List<PersonHandler> myPerson = new ArrayList<PersonHandler>();
    myPerson = EmployeePerson.getPersonList(myDB, personType);
    //get the list view reference
    listViewEmployeesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstView_Employees);

    sampleListAdapter myAdapter = new sampleListAdapter(this, R.layout.item_listviewitem, myPerson);
    myAdapter.personType = personType;
    listViewEmployeesList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

I'm really confused. what is causing this problem?
thanks in advance...

Comment: Use universal image loader.

Comment: @vipulmittal I actually had already posted an answer with the a lot better solution of Picasso (and believe me i used to be a UIL fan myself), but then I realized that the OP is not loading from the internet

Comment: You are right. But if all images are in drawable then just setImageResource(R.drawable.exclamation) should work well enough.

Comment: UIL can work with drawables as well check the code below.

Comment: thanks for your response. @vipulmittal no, not all the images are in drawable, the only image in drawable is default picture, the picture for potter. others are picked by user from the gallery. does UIL works for that too?

Answer (score 0):

Try to user Universal image loader to load images from drawable as well. 
Something like that this:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(context, "drawable://" + uri, profilePicture);
```

The uri will only have resource id in it.

Comment: actually I'm new to UIL, should I place the UIL setup in adapter constructor? i've done that and then replaced `profilePicture.setImageURI(uri);` with `imageLoader.displayImage(uri.toString(), profilePicture);` in `getView()` method. but the app crashes.

Comment: it says unfortunately app stopped working. it's some logical error I guess with profilePicture. i traced it but couldn't figure it out where the error happens. I even passed it's `String uri` argument the `path` variable but still no result even with the default picture in drawable.